# мягкий знак в словах типа "мышь"?

Tags: орфография

Мы с внуком зашли в тупик.Согласная Ш всегда твердая, значит она не может быть мягкой. Тем не менее, слово мышь пишется с мягким знаком! Таким образом, мягкий знак делает гласную Ш мягкой? Какой смысл ставить Ь знак после согласной, которая никогда не будет мягкой?

Comment: Мягкий знак стоИт там, чтобы показать, что это - женский род.

Comment: @VictorBazarov не **для** того чтобы, а **потому что**. Мягкий знак там - это архаизм (когда-то он произносился, как сверхкраткое "и"). А женский род - это просто проверочное правило.

Comment: @CITBL, поясните разницу )))

Comment: Кстати, Viktor, постарайтесь не убить в своем замечательном внуке эту способность задавать вопросы. И по русскому языку - и вообще любые. Я вот уже более полувека ношу в себе некоторую обиду на взрослых, которые отмахивались от меня, не вдумываясь в суть мной спрашиваемого.

Comment: @behemothus **для** и **чтобы** обозначает цель. Никто не сидел и не решал задачу "а давай-ка мы добавим на конец мягкий знак, чтобы показать, что такие слова относятся к женскому роду".

Answer (score 5):

Мягкий знак не всегда обозначал мягкость согласных и даже не всегда назывался мягким знаком

**ПРО МЯГКИЙ И ТВЕРДЫЙ ЗНАКИ**

В определённый исторический период буквы Ь и Ъ обозначали **редуцированные** (очень короткие) гласные, сходные **с  О и Е**; они соответственно употреблялись **после твёрдых и мягких  согласных.** После исчезновения  из языка этих кратких гласных буквами Ь и Ъ стали обозначать только ТВЁРДОСТЬ И МЯГКОСТЬ предыдущих согласных. После реформы 1918 года Ъ после твёрдых согласных больше не употреблялся, а мягкость или твёрдость согласного обозначалась наличием или отсутствием Ь.

**ПРО ШИПЯЩИЕ**

Так как  шипящие Ж, Ш, Ч, Щ являются непарными по твёрдости/мягкости, то наличие Ь (или Ъ) знака после них уже после «падения редуцированных» (XI- XIII вв) стало восприниматься только в качестве **грамматического признака.** Для примера можно привести дореформенное написание некоторых слов: неудачъ, лучъ, Ивановичъ, но: ложь, развлечь, пьёшь. После отмены Ъ грамматические формы стали различаться отсутствием или наличием Ь.

Хотя  выбор Ь в различных частях речи складывался исторически, в современной орфографии  Ь после шипящих приобретает грамматическую функцию. Это уже не мягкий знак, **а грамматический знак.**

**Традиция - вещь хорошая, но  зачем нам сейчас нужен такой знак?** Во-первых, с помощью Ь различается женский и мужской род существительных (вещь, но: плащ). Во-вторых, наличие или отсутствие Ь определяет сходное написание некоторых частей речи (стричь/мыть, спрячь/встань).

Поэтому правила выбора грамматического Ь после Ж, Ш, Ч, Щ - это  удачное решение. В случае с шипящими мы получаем **определенную степень свободы** (можем писать или не писать Ь), и мы не только распорядились этой степенью свободы весьма разумно, но даже сохранили традицию написания.

Comment: Vera, держите плюс от меня заслуженный, но при чем тут "мыть"?

Comment: Я намекаю на то, что  в неопределенной форме глагола (мыть)  и в повелительном наклонении (встань)  мы всегда пишем Ь,  в том числе после шипящих (стричь, спрячь), причем после шипящих это грамматический знак.

Comment: Тяжело такие намеки понять)))

Answer (score 4):

> ...мягкий знак делает гласную Ш мягкой?

Не делает.

> Какой смысл ставить Ь знак после согласной, которая никогда не будет
>   мягкой?

Такова **традиция**. См. [ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=28#pp28):

> **§ 32.** После ***ж, ш, ч, щ*** буква ***ь*** пишется ***по традиции*** в следующих грамматических формах:
>
> а) **на конце форм им. п. ед. ч. существительных жен. рода 3-го
>   склонения**, напр.: *рожь, блажь, мышь, фальшь, ночь, мелочь, вещь,
>   помощь.*
>
> б) в окончании 2-го лица ед. ч. глаголов настоящего и будущего
>   времени...
>
> в) в формах повелительного наклонения глаголов...
>
> г) в неопределенной форме глаголов...
>
> Буква ***ь*** после шипящих пишется также на конце наречий и частиц...

===

> Какой смысл ставить Ь знак после согласной, которая никогда не будет мягкой?

Вы с внуком не первые из тех, кто задавался таким вопросом.

**Букчина, Калакуцкая и Чельцова  в книге "Письма об орфографии" (1969) пишут:**

> Предложение отменить ***ь*** после шипящих очень давнее; оно
>   выдвигалось ещё в ХIХ веке и вошло наравне с предложением отменить
>   ***ъ*** на конце слов в решения Комиссии 1904 г., в состав которой входили известные лингвисты Ф.Ф. Фортунатов, А.А. Шахматов и др.
>
> В "Предварительном сообщении Орфографической подкомиссии" (май 1904
>   г.) было записано:
>
> "2. В связи с уничтожением буквы ***ъ*** исключается  также и ***ь***
>   в конце слов, где она не показывает произношения, именно после ***ж,
>   ш, ч, щ,*** так как две первые буквы произносятся всегда твёрдо, а две
>   последние всегда мягко, что бы мы после них всегда ни писали. Поэтому
>   нужно писать ***рож, маж, настеж, мыш, ходиш, сердишся, лиш, ноч, печ,
>   жечся, помощ*** и т. д."
>
> Это предложение, как и некоторые другие, не вошло в декрет 1918 г.
>   **Если бы оно было принято в то время, то прошло бы, очевидно, так же
>   легко, как отмена *ъ* на конце слов.**

Рассматривалось такое предложение и в 1964 году…

Answer (score 1):

Смысл тут один. Сохранение исторической преемственности. Она же - "традиция". какой смысл в **сохранении** это традиции - вот это отдельный вопрос. Так нагляднее, видимо.

Вам с внуком, видимо, стоит понять две вещи.
~1. Орфография не всегда следует понятным принципам, традиция вещь немаловажная. Отказ от неё породил бы массу вопросов. От исторической правды отказываться просто так не стоит.

~2. Мягкий знак, как и большинство букв (графем) в русском письме, несет не одну функцию, а несколько. В данном случае это функция - смыслоразличительная. Сравните - "Золотая **рожь**" и "Как тут много кривых **рож**!"

Можно, в принципе, в данном случае отказаться от сохранения этого знака, большой беды не будет, но и пользы особой в том нет. А исторический принцип нарушится.

Comment: Польза все таки будет. На урок или два для школьников сократится занятия по русскому языку. И это время можно потратить на что нибудь другое полезное. Хотя и добавится несколько омонимов в письменной речи (в устной они и так есть).

Comment: Мелковато будет. Зато сколько придется потратить времени на объяснения, зачем в старых книжках этот знак ставили.

Comment: Не думаю, что много времени займет сказать, что это потому что раньше были другие правила. Гораздо меньше чем на отработку этого правила, и проверку насколько усвоен материал.

Comment: Не думаю, что "сказать" будет достаточно

Answer (score 1):

Ь здесь пишется по ПРИНЦИПУ ГРАФИКО-МОРФОЛОГИЧЕСКИХ АНАЛОГИЙ.

Буква ь - графический уравнитель парадигм склонения существительных типа ночь, рожь (как ель) и как графический уравнитель морфологических категорий повелительного наклонения: режь (как брось), а также инфинитива: беречь(как брать). Это происходит  только на письме, что, однако, при известной автономности письменной речи чрезвычайно важно. Традиционно считается, что написание буквы ь выполняет функцию грамматического сигнала

1: буква ь сигнализирует о женском роде слов ночь, рожь и т.д.

Однако "сигнализирующая функция" буквы ь в определенных категориях слов - это лишь следствие, а не причина его употребления. Причиной является влияние определенных графико-морфологических моделей, т.е. морфологическая аналогия. Слова женского рода типа рожь, ночь дают одинаковую графическую парадигму склонения со словами типа дверь (ср.: **дверь - дверью, рожь - рожью, ночь - ночью**), в то время как слова мужского рода типа врач, шалаш имеют такую же графическую парадигму, как и слова типа стол (ср.: **стол - столом, врач - врачом, шалаш - шалашом**).

При распределении слов по типам склонения употребление буквы ь после шипящих в качестве **ведущего** признака **родового** значения слов в русских грамматиках обычно не учитывается. К третьему склонению относят существительные женского рода с "основой на мягкие согласные и на шипящие ж и ш"

2. Однако то, что буква ь создает графическое единообразие парадигм склонения, учитывается как ведущий признак при подаче этого материала нерусским.

С чисто звуковой точки зрения употребление мягкого знака после шипящих в словах женского рода является избыточным: и без него конечные /ч/ и /щ/ (ночь, мощь) произносились бы мягко, как произносятся они в словах ключ, плющ, а в словах рожь, мышь с чисто звуковой точки зрения написание мягкого знака иногда даже вредно, так как, например, при изучении русского языка в условиях диалекта может натолкнуть на неправильное мягкое произношение твердых /ш/ и /ж/.

Буква ь после шипящих в повелительной форме графически закрепляет, конечно, относительное единообразие, поскольку в языковом отношении эти формы не едины: одни из них образуются при помощи суффиксов /и/ (сиди) и /ы/ (лежи), другие выступают в виде чистой основы (гуляй, кинь). Буква ь графически объединяет только формы повелительного наклонения с чистыми основами на шипящие (не плачь) и формы повелительного наклонения с чистыми основами на конечный парный по твердости-мягкости согласный (кинь).

Кстати, В древнерусском языке в соответствующих грамматических формах после всех шипящих, поскольку они были исконно мягкими, писался "ерь" (т.е. ь как знак редуцированного гласного переднего ряда). Писалось не только дочь, ночь, мышь, но и врачь, ножь, мужь и т.п. Однако со временем, после отвердения /ж/ и /ш/ и исчезновения редуцированных гласных, эти написания "сбились". После ж и ш начинают употреблять не только ь, но и ъ. В "Российской грамматике" Ломоносова представлены написания: речь, дочь, ключь, мечь, но : ковшъ, ножъ.

Итак, буква ь (фонетически отнюдь не необходимая) употребляется прежде всего не как сигнал различия (чтобы по его наличию или отсутствию различать ночь и врач, плач и не плачь), а как письменный **графический уравнитель однозначных (грамматических) категорий**

Comment: Людмила, "уравнитель"- это слишком круто для внука. В принципе формулировка "для различения" вполне достаточна. За ней стоит то же самое.

Comment: Я ж деду объясняю, а уж он найдёт, как объяснить внуку на его уровне. Мы ж возраста его не знаем: 5-класснику одними словами, 8-класснику можно и "уравнитель".А вообще, младшие классы быстрее поймут. У меня был случай, когда ещё в ЕГЭ были задания по фонетике, внучатый племянник (3 класс)под дверью ждал, не выдержал, вошёл в 11 класс:"Тупые что ль, йотированных букв не понимаете?" И всё разложил по полочкам, не знаю, смеяться или плакать.

Answer (score 0):

Мягкий знак в данном случае ставится по орфографическим правилам и выполняет определенную грамматическую роль: является показателем 3-го склонения имен существительных. Я не вижу здесь связи с традицией, хотя согласный звук [Ш] в действительности всегда твердый.

Comment: Это архаизм. Такой же как и когда-то твердый знак на конце слов. Когда-то буква "ь" обозначала звук, который поизносился как короткое "и", перед которым согласный звук смягчался. Потом звук "ь" исчез из русского языка, а звук "ш" - отвердел.

Comment: @Tangrix Не всегда. Исторически все шипящие в русском - мягкие. Но традиция не в том. Традиция как раз в соблюдении орфографических правил, о которых вы и говорили. Правила эти были придуманы очень много лет назад для удобства смыслозазличения. То, что эту идею не выкинули ни в 1918 ни в 1954, и есть традиция.

Comment: @CITBL, во-первых, не архаизм, а историзм. Во-вторых, пример неудачный. Твердый знак на концах слов почти никакого смысла не нес. Мягкий является показателем рода или грамматической формы. Нельзя сравнивать.

Comment: @behemothus а какой смысл показывать род специальным знаком?  Никакого. В других случаях мы же без этого обходимся.

Comment: Какой смысл показывать род – вопрос неправильно поставлен. Какой смысл это выбрасывать? – вот правильный вопрос. И ответ: никакого смысла.

Comment: @Niemand Я не предлагаю выбрасывать, хотя если бы выбросили, я был бы за. Смысл тот же самый, как и при отмене Ъ и особенно Ѣ. А именно: сокращение времени нужного на усвоение правил правописания. Но конечно это слишком мелкое изменение, чтобы ради него одного затевать реформу.

Comment: "а какой смысл показывать род специальным знаком" - а какогй смысл вообще писать буквенным алфавитом? Используйте иероглифы, как китайцы - и будет вам "Щщастте". CITBL, искать смысл там где надо просто принять к сведению, - это, конечно, интересно, но бессодержательно.

Comment: @behemothus Смысл писать буквенным алфавитом есть. Так как это имеет целый ряд преимуществ над иероглифами. Только при чем здесь это? Я что-то говорил про иероглифы? Не понимаю аналогии. Я и не ищу смысл в мягком знаке в слове "мышь", тем более что его там и нет. Это вы первый заговорили что он там есть.

Comment: Еще какой. А вот китайцы 4.5К лет никак его разглядеть не могут.